# java generics - specifying the generic type

Tags: java, generics

Ok here is what I want to do..
opencsv has following constructor..

```
CsvToBean<T> csv2Bean=new CsvToBean<T>();
```

In it's current form, it will take any object. so following works fine for me.

```
CsvToBean<HoldbackModel> holdbackModelCsv=new CsvToBean<HoldbackModel>();
```

I would like to write a generic helper which will wrap the opencsv calls. I want to restrict it to any objects of classes which extend my marker class CsvRecord.

```
public static <T extends CsvRecord> List<T> readCsvRecords(InputStream srcRecords,     InputStream templateCsv, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    // here i want to pass the class clazz to the CsvBean.. but don't know how!!
    CsvToBean<T> csv2Bean=new CsvToBean<T>();
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You are going the right way, just need a little bit adjustment.

```
public static <T extends CsvRecord> List<T> readCsvRecords(InputStream srcRecords, InputStream templateCsv) {
    CsvToBean<T> csv2Bean = new CsvToBean<T>();
}
```

Comment: You don't need the Class parameter because Java Generic type parameters are not Objects that you pass at runtime. They are just hints to the compiler. At compile time when you try to call readCsvRecords, Java will look at the call site and try to infer a type for T. It must extends CsvRecord because you said so. And that's it. All the other references to T are unconstrained. When do you need to pass a Class object? Let's say you wanted to return T instead of List<T>. You might have to cast to T. Then the method needs a real Class object to do the cast.